# Retrieve data from database and display it in drop down format. And use the same drop down list as an input.

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, forms

i have been having the following problem .I am able to retrieve the data from database and display it in a drop down menu.But i dont know how to use the same drop down list as the input and embed it in a form.My code is as follows.Here project names are retrieved from the database and are displayed in the form of drop down list.Now i need to use the same drop down list in the form(HTML form) which will be used to input data into another table.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
include 'connect.php' ;
$tbl_name="projects";


$sql="SELECT project_name FROM $tbl_name ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error());  
}
?>


<form name="resources" action="hourssubmit.php"  method="post" >

<?php
echo "<select name='project_name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<option value='" . $row['project_name'] ."'>" . $row['project_name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question itself tells the answer. you created drop down from table and it display in your form. Then you can use as input field. When you submit then you can get the value using $get or $post method

Comment: hey yes,i can display a drop down list,but how can i use the same drop down list in a html form as an input,i am getting stuck at the syntax,as i am a compelete newbie it would be very helpful for me if you can post the correct code for it.

Comment: Actually You struggle to explain what you want. Do one thing
In your hourssubmit.php try to fetch $prjName = $_post['project_name']; and also add submit button in your form.